# TextView IOS Swift - Design em forma de Balão

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Olá pessoal, gostaria de saber como eu faço uma textView dessa em ios com swift ?

Desde já muito grato pela atenção.

Comment: Você deseja implementar um chat, tipo o Facebook Messenger, ou apenas mostrar uma mensagem isolada?

Comment: Somente uma mensagem isolada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você vai mostrar uma mensagem isolada, pode fazer usando um UITextView padrão com um UIImageView atrás dele.

O TextView tem fundo transparente e contém apenas o texto. O ImageView contém a imagem de fundo, no caso, o balão. Para que a imagem não fique distorcida, utilize `resizableImageWithCapInsets`, o qual permite definir os insets das bordas da imagem que serão preservados quando a imagem for redimensionada.
Caso o balão tenha as arestas afastadas das bordas, use `textContainerInset` para afastar o texto das bordas. Ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var textView : UITextView!
    @IBOutlet var imageView : UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var textViewHeightConstraint : NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var image : UIImage = UIImage(named:"test.png")!
        image = image.resizableImageWithCapInsets(UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 100, 30, 80))
        imageView.image = image

        textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 20, 0, 10)
        textView.scrollEnabled = false
        //redimensiona textView de acordo com o texto
        var sizeThatFitsTextView : CGSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSizeMake(textView.frame.size.width, CGFloat.max))
        textViewHeightConstraint.constant = sizeThatFitsTextView.height
    }
}
```

No exemplo eu criei uma constrait de altura para o textView no storyboard e alterei o seu valor de acordo com a altura do texto. Também fiz com que a altura do imageView seja sempre igual a do textView, usando constraints. Se quiser pode fazer tudo isso pelo código.

Se por acaso implementar uma lista com múltiplas mensagens, pode adaptar a ideia para usar UITableViewCell ou melhor ainda, usar uma das várias bibliotecas para este fim, como https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController